# Can I set up an ad hoc connection if my base laptop is connected to a Wi-Fi connection?

Tags: windows-vista, wireless-networking, ad-hoc-network, hotspot

I have a Vista computer and cannot download Connectify as it requires Windows 7. Is it possible for me to connect to the Internet via Wi-Fi and share that connection through the same Wi-Fi adapter in my laptop?

Comment: Please do not type in all CAPS.

Answer (score 3):

This depends on the exact hardware, but the odds are strongly in favor of 'no'.  Almost all wireless adapters only support a single concurrent connection; this would require two (one for the normal network, one for the ad-hoc network).

You could add a second wireless adapter, though.

Comment: well I know there are downloadable programs that ALLOW IT LIKE CONNECTIFY OR VIRTUAL ROUTER, BUT THESE DO NOT SUPPORT VISTA.... ONLY WINDOWS 7 AND OTHERS

Comment: IT'S NOT NECESSARY TO SHOUT.  And Connectify doesn't work that way.  The input and output have to be on different adapters, so you can take internet from Ethernet or an Aircard and then rebroadcast as a WiFi access point to share that connection.  I believe it does have a repeater function (which basically causes it to retransmit everything it sees on the network, which slows it down but does provide signal boost) but this is for a single network.  You can't have the one WiFi network and the other ad-hoc network, it's not the same - a single adapter can only be on a single network at a time!

Comment: And even if the repeater function is what you want (rather than setting up a second connection as an ad hoc, which is what you specified in the question title), I don't know of a product that supports Vista and claims to do that.  And if that IS an acceptable alternative you should edit the question to indicate so.